# castle windsor - batch registration works on some classes only

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am have the following row to batch register implementations:

```
container.Register(Types.FromAssembly(typeof (BaseBll<>).Assembly)
         .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudBll<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

it works on 2 classes out of 4 event though they are exactlly the same.

```
public interface ICrudBll<T>{} //main interface

public interface IBrandBll : ICrudBll<Brand>{}
public class BrandBll : BaseBll<Brand>, IBrandBll{}// WORKING

public interface IRoleBll : ICrudBll<Role>{}
public class RoleBll : BaseBll<Role>, IRoleBll{}// NOT WORKING
```

it is suppose to be injected to:

```
//WORKING
public class BrandController : BaseApiController<Brand>
{
    public BrandController(IBrandBll bll) : base(bll)
    {
    }
}

// NOT WORKING
public class RoleController : BaseApiController<Role>
{
    public RoleController(IRoleBll bll)
        : base(bll)
    {
    }
}
```

I dont see any differences between the classes and the interfaces, but yet some works and some not. (they are all in the same assembly).

This is the ERROR:

```
Type CrudApp.BusinessLogic.IUserBll is abstract.
 As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service 'CrudApp.BusinessLogic.IUserBll'. Did you forget to proxy it?
```

Again, the `IBrandBll` is working and the `IRoleBll` not.

I made a test, and injected the failed ones explicitly, and it worked:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IRoleBll>().ImplementedBy<RoleBll>().LifestyleTransient());
```

Thanks

Comment: What does that mean 'some work and some not'? Do you get sn exception?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - have a look at the last row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
container.Register(Types.FromAssembly(typeof (BaseBll<>).Assembly)
     .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudBll<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

to

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(typeof (BaseBll<>).Assembly)
     .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudBll<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

The statements above will also register interfaces, and it seems you only want classes to be registered.

**this is actually what worked:**

```
var types = AllTypes
     .FromAssembly(typeof (ICrudBll<>).Assembly)
     .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudBll<>))
     .WithService.FromInterface(typeof (ICrudBll<>));
```

container.Register(types);

Comment: @Shazam, If i'm correct AllTypes is deprecated and is replaced by Classes. What version of Windsor are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states the problem is with IUserBll - not shown in your code snippets.

I bet IUserBll inherits from ICrudBll, which would explain the error - try to narrow down the type selection criteria to classes, excluding the interfaces:

```
Types.FromAssembly(typeof (BaseBll<>).Assembly)
     .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudBll<>))
```

returns everything, including interfaces. Try something like

```
Types.FromAssembly(typeof (BaseBll<>).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsClass)
    .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudBll<>))
```

Comment: Hi, First yes. `IUserBll` inherits from `ICrudBll` but it is like the rest of the interfaces. can you please offer a solution, I don't understand how to solve this. - thanks

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error (on every dependency required): `'CrudApp.Client.Mvc.Controllers.BrandController' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'CrudApp.BusinessLogic.IBrandBll' which was not registered.`